# Code inserted on input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, popup

I have a form in PHP that is making trouble, so I need some help.

When an user writes a postal code (Código postal) and clicks "Buscar" the script looks into the DB and fills the rest of the form with info. I already managed various scenarios:

1. If the postal code doesn't exist it gives yo a Warning.
2. If the postal code it's correct it fills up the form with the postal code, city and state.

And my problem comes with the third one. If the postal code exists but theres more than one city using that postal code (it can happen with the spanish postal codes...) I want to open a popup, new window, dynamic popup... with a select so the user can select the correct city...

I managed to detect when you put a postal code that is used by more than one city, but the problem is that at the moment of triggering the script for the popup, instead of working it just show the code on the "Población" and "Provincia" inputs...

Here is the code I'm using:

**index.php**

```
<input type="text" maxlength="5" class="form-control" id="postal_code" name="postal_code" placeholder="Código postal" pattern="[0-9]{5}">
<button class="btn btn-info btn-flat" type="button" onclick="updateCityState();">Buscar</button>
<input type="text" id="city" class="form-control" placeholder="Población">
<input type="text" id="state" class="form-control" placeholder="Provincia">
........
<script src="popup.js"></script>
<script>var ajax = getHTTPObject();

        function getHTTPObject()
        {
            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
              // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
              xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
              // code for IE6, IE5
              xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } else {
              //alert("Your browser does not support XMLHTTP!");
            }
            return xmlhttp;
        }

        function updateCityState()
        {
            if (ajax)
            {
                var zipValue = document.getElementById("postal_code").value;
                if(zipValue)
                {
                    var url = "get_cities.php";
                    var param = "?postal_code=" + escape(zipValue);

                    ajax.open("GET", url + param, true);
                    ajax.onreadystatechange = handleAjax;
                    ajax.send(null);
                }
            }
        }
        function handleAjax()
        {
            if (ajax.readyState == 4)
            {
                if( ajax.responseText.length ) {
                    citystatearr = ajax.responseText.split(",");
                    city.value = citystatearr[0]; 
                    state.value = citystatearr[1];
                }else{
                    city.value = "No existe";
                    state.value = "No existe";
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

**get_cities.php**

```
<?php
include_once('../../../connect.html');
//perform lookup
$title = ($_GET['postal_code']);
$statement = $connection->prepare ("SELECT city, state FROM cities, states WHERE cities.state_id = states.state_id AND cities.postal_code = ?");
$statement->execute(array($title));
$statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$items = array();
while ($r = $statement->fetch()) {
    //$arrayName = array($r = $statement->fetch());
    $items[] = $r;
}

if (count($items) == '1'){

    $newArray = $items[0];
    echo $newArray['city'].",".$newArray['state']; 
}elseif (count($items) == '0'){
        echo "Doesn't exist".","."Doesn't exist";
    }else{
        <script type="text/javascript">
centerPopup();
        loadPopup();
</script>

    <div id="popupContact">
    <a id="popupContactClose">x</a>
    <h1>Title of our cool popup, yay!</h1>
    <p id="contactArea">
        Here we have a simple but interesting sample of our new stuning and smooth popup. As you can see jQuery and CSS does it easy...
        <br/><br/>
        We can use it for popup-forms and more... just experiment!
        <br/><br/>
        Press ESCAPE, Click on X (right-top) or Click Out from the popup to close the popup!
        <br/><br/>
        <a href="http://www.yensdesign.com"><img src="logo.jpg" alt="Go to yensdesign.com"/></a>
    </p>
</div>
<div id="backgroundPopup"></div>
}

?>
```

**popup.js**

```
   /***************************/
//@Author: Adrian "yEnS" Mato Gondelle
//@website: www.yensdesign.com
//@email: yensamg@gmail.com
//@license: Feel free to use it, but keep this credits please!                  
/***************************/

//SETTING UP OUR POPUP
//0 means disabled; 1 means enabled;
var popupStatus = 0;

//loading popup with jQuery magic!
function loadPopup(){
    //loads popup only if it is disabled
    if(popupStatus==0){
        $("#backgroundPopup").css({
            "opacity": "0.7"
        });
        $("#backgroundPopup").fadeIn("slow");
        $("#popupContact").fadeIn("slow");
        popupStatus = 1;
    }
}

//disabling popup with jQuery magic!
function disablePopup(){
    //disables popup only if it is enabled
    if(popupStatus==1){
        $("#backgroundPopup").fadeOut("slow");
        $("#popupContact").fadeOut("slow");
        popupStatus = 0;
    }
}

//centering popup
function centerPopup(){
    //request data for centering
    var windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    var windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    var popupHeight = $("#popupContact").height();
    var popupWidth = $("#popupContact").width();
    //centering
    $("#popupContact").css({
        "position": "absolute",
        "top": windowHeight/2-popupHeight/2,
        "left": windowWidth/2-popupWidth/2
    });
    //only need force for IE6

    $("#backgroundPopup").css({
        "height": windowHeight
    });

}


//CONTROLLING EVENTS IN jQuery
$(document).ready(function(){

    //LOADING POPUP
    //Click the button event!


    //CLOSING POPUP
    //Click the x event!
    $("#popupContactClose").click(function(){
        disablePopup();
    });
    //Click out event!
    $("#backgroundPopup").click(function(){
        disablePopup();
    });
    //Press Escape event!
    $(document).keypress(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode==27 && popupStatus==1){
            disablePopup();
        }
    });

});
```

So when the script detects that the user looks for a postal code that belongs to more than one city and clicks "Buscar" instead of opening the popup it fills the form with the content of popup.js . I don't really know why is that happening, so any help will be appreciated!!

Comment: Have you checked if, while you were testing your code, there was popup block or ads-blocker activated in your browser?

Comment: You are running your javascript serverside in a php file. That will never work. Load popup.js in the header of `index.php` and instead of `include_once('popup.js');` echo some response that triggers `centerpopup() and loadpopup()` clientside.

Comment: Okay, I did some changes on the code... But still after looking for that postal code the rest of the file and JS is getting filled on the form.

Comment: <img src="http://i.imgur.com/1Z0S7UV.png"> That's what's happening...

Comment: If you're using Chrome, Firefox, Opera or the new version of Internet Explorer, you can see how the DOM changes dynamically with the "Inspect Element" (or similar) to understand the problem easier. Can you see the HTML with the problem?

Answer (score 0):

So, if I read your question and comments correctly, this isn't exactly the code you are working on, but I seem to get your point. Info for others, he is using echo in the else clause in the script get_cities.php and now to the solution.

Your ajax handler needs an exception.

```
function handleAjax()
{
   if (ajax.readyState == 4)
   {
      if( ajax.responseText.length && ajax.responseText.indexOf("script") < 0 ) { //<-- here
        citystatearr = ajax.responseText.split(",");
        city.value = citystatearr[0]; 
        state.value = citystatearr[1];
     }
```

Then add a new condition

```
 else if ( ajax.responseText.lengt && ajax.responseText.indexOf("script") != -1 ){
   // as I see you have also jquery I will use it here
   $('body').append(ajax.responseText);
 }
```

and then the rest of your code

```
 else{
        city.value = "No existe";
        state.value = "No existe";
      }
    }
  }
```

But this whole code will not solve all your problems you are going to face. I would suggest to create a modal window inside your html(php) and then just fill it with informations from the ajax.